# How can I calculate some students in my database?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have such entities:

[image]

There are **teachers**, **students**, **languages**, **courseGroups** and a junction table **GroupStudent**

Every **courseGroup** can have only one teacher and one language, but every teacher and language can have multiple courses.

Also, there are students. Every student can have a few courses and every course can have a few students.

I'm not sure about this. Is it the right scheme?

Why do I think so?
I have a task. I have to calculate the number of students in every group, who study English.

**The problem:** I don't know how to find students who study English. It would be easier if student could have only one course. Then I'd have just check all English courses. However, student can have a few courses.

**Example:** Student Stepan has (CourseGroupid=1) an English course and (CourseGroupid=2) a Spanish course. I have to calculate this student for both groups.

**P.S.** I'd be very grateful if you'd just hit me is it possible to complete the task with this database or how to remake it :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a `DISTINCT` select on `Students.Id` to get every student at max once. Then `JOIN` GroupStudent, CourseGroups and Languages. Lastly add a `WHERE` clause on Languages.Name = 'English'. You should be able to figure out the exact SQL on your own